# Accessing carbon objects

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have this:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
print_r($now);
```

This gives the result:

```
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2016-09-28 06:03:16.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

And when i try to access:

```
print_r($now->date);
```

It gives the error:

> Unknown getter 'date'

Comment: `$now = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
 print_r($now);` gives only date.

Comment: Not sure why, but `$now->date` is working for me. Maybe you are modifying `$now` before calling `print_r($now->date);`?

Comment: Carbon does not have a getter for date. What do you need to access. If you need the output like in the date you can do `$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')`

Comment: @chanafdo `Carbon` extends `DateTime` which has a public `date` property.

Comment: My bad. It seems that the `date` property being accessible is a bug. Check @Nabeel's answer and @chanafdo's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use:

```
echo $now;
```

to print the date. Carbon has __toString method which automatically returns date in string format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$timestamp = get_object_vars($now);
print_r($timestamp);
```

It returns array.

And then you can :

```
echo $timestamp["date"];
```